# Gitlab Runner Shell Executor For Running Jobs in Multiple Servers

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed my gitlab-runner to 3 servers, configured it as shell executor. My runner is specific runner not a shared runner. I'm not using tags. My purpose is, I want to execute the .gitlab-ci.yml instructions in 3 servers simultaneously. My template yaml is below.

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage:
    - hostname
```

When executing this yml, I expect this yaml to executed in 3 servers but it only executes in 1 of my servers and when I trigger the runner again, it executes in my other server.
Is shell executor capable of doing this? How to do that? Should I change my method?

NOTE: After posting this, I tried with tag method.When I register my runners, I created specific tags for the servers and use those tags in gitlab-ci.yaml file to run the jobs. With this method, all the jobs run in related tags but they didn't run simultenaously. Also this method results in replicated lines in gitlab-ci.yaml because I will do same mostly things in all of my servers.

Answer (score 2):

In GitLab CI, when a pipeline is executed all the jobs able to run are placed in a FIFO (first-in, first-out) queue. If a gitlab-runner is not currently running a job, it constantly polls this queue to see if there is a job available that this runner can process (based on tags, the project it came from, available quota if using gitlab.com, etc.) and if so, pulls down the job and starts executing it.

Each job is a single object in the queue, so once a runner grabs it and starts working it, no other runner can grab it from the queue, so it's impossible for a single job to be run on multiple runners.

What you need is to have multiple identical jobs running in parallel, and thankfully GitLab CI has a feature to do just that as long as you're using GitLab on version 15.9 or later.

If you just want the same job to run multiple times without any variation in the different jobs, you simply add the `parallel` keyword to your job definition and pass it an integer value that represents the number of times you want it to run:

```yaml
# Using the example from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel
test:
  script: rspec
  parallel: 5
```

When this pipeline is run, GitLab will create 5 jobs called "test" that each run the command `rspec`, and will place them into the queue.

One thing to note about the `parallel` keywork is that they may not actually run in parallel after the jobs are created and put into the queue. How the jobs are ran depends on the number of gitlab-runner processes you have available and the configuration you use. For the sake of simplicity lets say you have a single gitlab-runner process and it's configured to only run one job at a time. In this case the runner will pull down the first job and run it, but the other four will have to wait until the first job completes, and the fifth job will have to wait for all four in the queue ahead of it.

However if you have 5 gitlab-runners or if you have your runners configured to be able to run multiple jobs in parallel (for more information on how to configure runners to run multiple jobs, see the [documentation here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#runner-configuration) all 5 jobs will run at once.

Now if you want each of your jobs to run in parallel but on different runners in different regions, you should limit which runners this job can run in via a specific tag on the job and on all three of these runners, and they should be configured to only run a single job at a time (the `concurrent` field should be `1`). If these runners can run more than 1 job at a time, one of them might grab multiple jobs from the queue.